# How To Stop Duplicates Being Listed On PHP Results?

Tags: php, search

I've made up a PHP script which assigns a score to listings on a website and assigns it to the results page. I have got it to work in that it shows the score and the details but it keeps listing the same results over and over.

I can't work out what it is doing but there is a small section of code I was hoping would prevent duplicate listings. Could anyone give it a tweak and see if I am going wring somewhere?

**The Code is:**

```
$dupCatch .= $adId.","; 
$dupResults = explode(',', $dupCatch);

foreach($dupResults as $dupResult){

  if($dupResult == $adId){
    print "";
  } else {
    print $showResults;
    $scoreBox = 'THIS IS THE SCORE: '  . $finalScore . '';
    print $scoreBox;
  }

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Jack

Comment: Nowhere inside your loop do you change the value of $finalScoare, or $showResults, or $scoreBox. And you wonder why nothing changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you add your current `$adId` to the duplicate list *before* you check if it is there - which it will always be, of course.

Storing a bunch of numbers in a string, `explode`ing it every time, is a little weird, use an array instead. You also don't need to manually loop through all the items, just use [`in_array()`](http://de.php.net/in_array)

```
if( !in_array($adId, $dupCatch) ){
    print $showResults;
    $scoreBox = 'THIS IS THE SCORE: '  . $finalScore . '';
    print $scoreBox;
}

$dupCatch[] = $adId;
```

Needless to say: it would be a better idea to fix the part that gives you the duplicate results in the first place.

Comment: Hi, there was a rogue "." flying around which was duplicating the first entry. I'm not new to PHP but never used the explode function before and mistakenly thought I could use it. Thanks for your solution man worked a charm!!

Answer (score 1):

You can either try to use `array_unique` from php side or use unique attribute at field in mysql this way duplicates can be prevent before even inserting them.